# Can I use #getlistat( to pull in alphabetical order? (coldfusion)

Tags: coldfusion

I am working on a site and the back-end developer is AWOL. 
Currently this line of code is pulling the first image in the directory based on most recently added. Is there anyway to pull first alphabetically?

```
<img width="920" height="300" 
   src="data/images/<cfoutput>#ListGetAt(pic, 1)#</cfoutput>" />
```

Thanks in advance, my knowledge of CF is very slim. Here is the CF code:

```
<cfquery name="HomePageImage" Datasource="PioneerPublic">
   SELECT ImageFull FROM HomePageImages WHERE Active = 1
</cfquery>
<cfset pic = "">    
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#HomePageImage.Recordcount#">
    <cfset pic = #ListAppend(pic, HomePageImage.ImageFull[x])#>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: In ListGetAt() function, there is a parameter called "pic" which contains a list of images. If you can show the logic of creating that list, then may be we can help you.

Comment: @TusharBhaware is right: you want to alter whatever query or code is generating `pic` list to be in alpha order instead of date order.

Comment: Im sorry I'm not sure exactly what you mean, as I said I am not well versed in CF or back-end developing. Can you elaborate on how I can do this?

Comment: check for the code which contains "pic" variable and show us 4 to 5 lines around that code. It would probably will look like this <cfset pic =

Comment: forget about anything i said, check the Henry's answer.

Comment: Add an `order by` clause to the query. Then you need not worry about query or queries or `listSort()` Simply add `order by imageFull` to the end of your query and you need not touch anything else. Let the DB handle sorting..DBs are good at that sort of thing.

Comment: @ScottStroz - You should post that as an answer. I was about to say the same thing. Based on what was posted, I see no reason to use lists here either.

Comment: @Atacoman - Also, do not pull back everything from that table if you only need a single record. The exact sql is database dependent (and you did not mention yours), but something like `LIMIT 1` (for MySQL) or `SELECT TOP 1...` (for SQL Server).

Comment: There might be reason's why he can't alther the query as is (perhaps it is used elswhere differently). That's why I suggested Q of a Q and/or valuelist. In the end listsort() is the shortest path - it's just seems like a waste not to refactor this code a bit :)

Comment: An alternative to top 1, or whatever, is to use the maxrows attribute of cfquery.

Comment: No, TOP/LIMIT is better. It ensures you only retrieve the rows needed from the db.  Some versions of CF (probably older ones) implemented maxrows incorrectly. They still returned all rows, then simply discarded the excess. So it was just as inefficient as `SELECT *`. Using database commands avoids the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ListSort()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListSort)

```
<cfoutput>#ListGetAt(ListSort(pic, "textnocase"), 1)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: damn... why didn't i think of that?

Comment: This looks like it is working, Thanks, I'm going to do a little more testing

Comment: @Henry He's not the one that asked the question

Comment: @Atacoman - hey make sure and read all these comments and posts - folks are working hard to give you a fast track CF Skill set :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an order by clause to the query. Then you need not worry about query or queries or `listSort()` Simply add order by `imageFull` to the end of your query and you need not touch anything else. Let the DB handle sorting..DBs are good at that sort of thing.

```
<cfquery name="HomePageImage" Datasource="PioneerPublic">
   SELECT ImageFull FROM HomePageImages WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY ImageFull
</cfquery>
```

Also, no need to loop over the query to create the list, simply use

```
<cfset pic = valueList( homepageImage.imageFull ) />
```

Answer (score 0):

You think *your* knowledge of ColdFusion is slim - your backend developer's knowledge needs some help as well :)

Once you have a query you can actually manipulate it directly in ColdFusion with something called "query of a query"  (nice name I know).

For example, the second query here would reorder the first query by AlphaNumeric in ASC order.

```
<cfquery name="HomePageImage" Datasource="PioneerPublic">
       SELECT ImageFull 
       FROM   HomePageImages 
       WHERE  Active = 1
</cfquery>

<Cfquery dbtype="query" name="HomePageImage">
    SELECT   ImageFull
    FROM     HomePageImage
    ORDER BY ImageFull ASC
</cfquery>


<cfset pic = "">    
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#HomePageImage.Recordcount#">
<cfset pic = ListAppend(pic, HomePageImage.ImageFull[x])>
</cfloop>
```

The main difference is the "dbtype" which is set to query - and the "tablename" in the query is the *name* of the original query. Neat eh?

As for the loop, it's wasted effort. ColdFusion has lots of ways to work with list that are leaner than that - including making a list out of a query colum. This snippet:

```
<cfset pic = ValueList(HomePageImage.ImageFull)/>
```

Does the same thing as your loop in a single function call. ColdFusion and lists are tight :)

FYI - you can also simply sort your original list using listSort as Henry suggested. I just thought I might give you some options.

Comment: @Atacoman - hey if your dev is really AWOL hit me up. We can lots of resources and we can help! We love bailing people out in emergencies :)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't want to pile on to much advice :)

Comment: Thanks This project is pretty much maxed on budget and I am just redesigning the visual aspects of the site. There may be some stuff in the future, where are you located?

Comment: Read my profile - it'll tell you how you can conact me. Thanks.